# When to use a single fragment and when to use multiple ones?

Tags: android, performance, user-interface, android-fragments

I'm creating an app and currently I'm doing it a way that I have only one fragment that has a layout. And evertyime a user clicks on an item on the navigation drawer the fragment gets called again, but dependent on the nav item click a different method is called. The methods don't do much different things. They only gather data and display it. Dependent on the click is which data they collect. So my question is, if the design is practically always the same and the data as well ( Always XML with the same structure ) should I use only 1 fragment? Because currently I have 1 fragment for 10 different type of data that can be recieved.

So the question is:

1 fragment, 1 layout?

10 fragments, 1 layout?

10 fragments, 10 layouts?

Which would be the best for performance reasons?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your requirement

- If you have one specific type of layout, by all means use one `Framgent`.
- If you have 10 different types of layouts, add 10 supporting `Fragments` for that layouts

In your case, your data stays the same and can work on one `Fragment` so don't bother with more than one. If your requirements for the other navigation items does change, you can consider creating other fragments with their layouts for each one that needs to change. This just helps with splitting up functionality and producing clean code.

Hope this helps

**EDIT**

Also consider using more than one `Fragment` if you add support for tablets. So in your instance add a `Fragment` for your navigation on the left that would show your list of navigation items (in stead of the navigation drawer like on the phone) and a fragment on the right that would show the current selected screen.